# one subclass does not inherit methods of the superclass but the other does. How to do it?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I have a SuperClass Named Vehicle which among other fields have a field/method called Chain. Now I have 2 Subclasses as Car and Bike. Now we know that Bike needs the Chain but the Car doesn't. So How in Java, we ensure that the Chain Attribute is only inherited in the Bike CLass but not in the Car Class?? Now I also have other classes like Bicycle which also needs the Chain attribute.... So how to do it?

Comment: you can't, your model is broken.  why don't you just declare Chain inside of Bike

Comment: Now I also have other classes like Bicycle which also needs the Chain attribute.... So how to do it? In that case for every class that needs Chain, I have to declare it inside every class?????

Answer (score 3):

You split it up

```
Vehicle
  * Other fields

MotorizedVehicle extends Vehicle
  * Specialized fields

NotMotorizedVehicle extends Vehicle
  * Chain

Car extends MotorizedVehicle

Bike extends NotMotorizedVehicle
```

Comment: I would used ChainDriveVehicle rather than NotMotorizedVehicle. Consider a horse drawn carriage, a dog sled, and a penny-farthing bicycle.

Comment: Yeah I didn't really put much thought in the same, just wanted to make the meaning somewhat clear. ChainDrive is definitely a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

> So how do we ensure that the `Chain` attribute is only inherited in the `Bike` class but not in the `Car` class

You can't.

Every subclass inherits all public fields and methods of its superclass.  If it didn't then Java would not be properly implementing subtyping / the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) which is at the core of Object Oriented Programming.

The correct solution is to not make the `Chain` attribute of `Vehicle`.

---

In the case of a method, Java does offer you an alternative; e.g.

```
  public class Tram extends Vehicle {
      ...
      public SteeringWheel getSteeringWheel() {
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                  "A tram has no steering wheel");
      }
  }
```

... but it is poor design, and you should avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `Chain` member field inside of Bike, where it belongs.  What you are asking for is not possible, nor is it really necessary.

Comment: Now I also have other classes like Bicycle which also needs the Chain attribute.... So how to do it? In that case for every class that needs Chain, I have to declare it inside every class?????

Comment: No, make a common Parent class of those classes.  That class will be a subclass of vehicle

Answer (score 0):

If your `Vehicle` class has `Chain` attribute then all the classes extending `Vehicle` will inherit `chain` attribute.  There is no exception in that because that is what Inheritance is in OOP. You can opt out not using chain property in `Car` class and in `Bike` you can use it.

Also as [Jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1864167/jeroen-vannevel) pointed out you can implement the class design like that also, which is I would generally do in such case.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad design to put `chain` member in `Vehicle` class, because not all `Vehicle`s have `chain`.

It is bad design to put members where they shall not be because of `code re-usability`.

If you really need to avoid code duplicates define an abstract class named `ChainedVehicle extends Vehicle` and add `chain` member to that, now you have a proper superclass for chained-vehicles.

Answer (score 0):

If your vehicles can be organized as a hierarchy, use Jeroen Vannevel's answer. If you need more flexibility, consider a set of interfaces representing vehicle features.

HasChain would be implemented by any chain drive vehicle, including Bicycle.

HasWheels would be implemented by MotorBike, Bicycle, Car, and HorseDrawnCarriage, but not by DogSled.

Motorized would be implemented by MotorBike and Car.

AnimalDrawn would be implemented by HorseDrawCarriage and DogSled.